# Maven release without tagging

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

The main idea of the question is: **is that a way to specify that maven release should skip tagging when performing a release?**

I have the following context: we have a TFS (Team Fundation Server) as a system that version our software. We also use a svn bridge that "talks" with the TFS and developers and CI tools use it. When performing a `mvn release:clean release:prepare release:perform` maven complains that it cannot find or create a tag (somehow translating the tag command of the svn into a similiar command in tfs crashes). Any suggestions are appreciated.

The error looks like this:

```
28-May-2013 15:51:04    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.1:branch (default-cli) on project spring-hibernate-mysql: The scm url is invalid.
28-May-2013 15:51:04    [ERROR] - scm:svn:https://${TFS_SERVER}:${PORT}/${PATH_TO_APP}/tags/dbDiagnostic-1.0.0-RELEASE url isn't a valid svn URL.
28-May-2013 15:51:04    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I mention that the url is ok, because the step before this, in a CI plan is a "`checkout sources`" step with the same url.

Comment: Can you show the scm area of your pom.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

The maven release plugin depends on the svn tag as it checks out the tagged version during the release process. So the answer is: No, there is no way to release without a tag.

The svn URL above is not valid, you should consider fixing it by resolving the variable substitutions.

Comment: Thanks Torsten for the answer. The variable are defined. I just replaced the error log with bindings variables to hide the paths.

Answer (score 1):

**To your question:**

You can disable remote tagging by setting the **remoteTagging** property to **false** as described in: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#remoteTagging

**Note** that in **only** works with SVN.

However, **the reason** for this error is most likely because maven **failed to create** the tag in the previous step, due to e.g. authentication failure or incorrect URL configuration ( see "tag base" attribute & etc ).

Comment: Thanks for your information. I did use the **remoteTagging** before and found out that it doesn't work for in my context. I also try to issue the command that maven executes in a command line and it was ok, but somehow the plugin and the svnbridge from codeplex does not work together